# Access start intent in Application class

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

It is possible to start the app with some Activity and some extras using ADB command like:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n mypackage/.myActivity -e param value
```

And then read these extras in Activity using

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("param")
```

Is there any way to access these extras in `Application::onCreate` before this Activity starts?

Comment: Instead of launching an activity with an intent with parameters, you can try launching your activity with an URL. See https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters and or https://developer.android.com/training/app-links. I don't think you can access them in Application::onCreate though.